# GroovyShell and the classpath

Tags: java, groovy

I'm starting to program with groovy and I wanted to know when I use GroovyShell (new File ("script.groovy"). txt) .evaluate (),
do script classes see dependencies in classpath or not, i try this example and it generate the following errors.

```
// main.groovy

@Grapes([
    @Grab(group='org.slf4j', module='slf4j-api', version='1.6.1'),
    @Grab(group='ch.qos.logback', module='logback-classic', version='0.9.28')
])

import groovy.lang.GroovyShell;
import java.io.File;

new GroovyShell().evaluate(new File("C:\\Users\\Dev\\Desktop\\logger.groovy").text);
```

```
// logger.groovy
import org.slf4j.*
import groovy.util.logging.Slf4j

@Slf4j
class HelloWorldSlf4j {
    def execute() {
        log.debug 'Execute HelloWorld.'
        log.info 'Simple sample to show log field is injected.'
    }
}

def helloWorld = new HelloWorldSlf4j()
helloWorld.execute()
```

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.Logger
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:869)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:979)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:967)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.transform.LogASTTransformation$AbstractLoggingStrategy.classNode(LogASTTransformation.java:346)
    ... 38 more
```

Comment: I was wrong in writing the problem , GroovyShell (new File ("script.groovy").text) .evaluate (),thank you in advance.

Comment: If you find a typo or wrong code, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60708434/edit) your question instead of "hiding" it in the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `logger.groovy` file to use the same classloader as `main.groovy` script, you need to pass it with the `GroovyShell` constructor. You can get the current classloader by calling `this.class.classLoader`.

```groovy
@Grapes([
    @Grab(group='org.slf4j', module='slf4j-api', version='1.6.1'),
    @Grab(group='ch.qos.logback', module='logback-classic', version='0.9.28')
])

import groovy.lang.GroovyShell
import java.io.File

new GroovyShell(this.class.classLoader).evaluate(new File("logger.groovy"))
```

Output:

```
$ groovy main.groovy
16:17:11.325 [main] DEBUG HelloWorldSlf4j - Execute HelloWorld.
16:17:11.327 [main] INFO  HelloWorldSlf4j - Simple sample to show log field is injected.
```